# linux - rename command to remove all text after final dash before extension in filename

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, rename

I have files in the following format:

```
word1 word2 word3-6b3kZ3q2i.mp4
word-8x2u3p6b4.mkv
```

Some of them have more than one dash. They all have a name followed by a final dash and an alphanumeric ID.

What I'm trying to do is remove the final dash and all text after it (except the file extension) from each filename in the current directory.

For example: `word1 word2 word3-6b3kZ3q2i.mp4` to `word1 word2 word3.mp4`

All of the solutions from similar questions that I've tried just don't seem to work. `rename` acts up whenever I place a dash inside the string to find or replace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the Perl-based `rename` command, you can use this `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/-[^.-]+(?=\.)//' *.*
```

**Regex Breakup:**

```
-       # match a hyphen
[^.-]+  # match 1 or more of any char that is not hyphen or dot
(?=\.)  # lookahead to assert that next char is dot
```

Comment: I'm not using perl rename. I'm using the rename from util-linux.